# Error manage in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, t-sql, plsql

i would like to convert a script t-SQL into pl/sql.
But i don't find how to manage error like in t-sql :

```
exec (bulk_cmd);
if @@error <> 0 goto lbl_end;
```

I found this : i've to create exception variable before make the exec. And do something like that :

```
        When NO_DATA_FOUND Then
            /* no value found*/…
        When TIMEOUT_ON_RESOURCE Then
            /* time out */…
        When ZERO_DIVIDE Then
            /* divide by zero*/…
        When Others Then
           /* others errors */…
```

It's really heavy... Andi know in T-SQL @@error is reserve to catch the error (if it's exist) of the last instruction (here the exec).
So i ask you if there is a method like this in pl/sql

Thank's !

Comment: Your comments to the answers reveal you're having an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe the actual problem you have. It's likely that your current SQL Server solution can't be simply "translated" to Oracle. Btw. the current answers correctly address your question so you should upvote them.

Comment: Hi, i read about the XY-problem. And it's possible. i go little around my problem. In fact i just have to translate my script t-sql into pl/sql. And the error manage is in. so my two last comments are my script to 'convert' so if someone can help me. Or i made a new question with "How to convert my script" and it's not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found everything you need. Just use either anonymous block `BEGIN...END;`

```
BEGIN
   bulk_cmd;
EXCEPTION
        When NO_DATA_FOUND Then
            /* no value found*/…
        When TIMEOUT_ON_RESOURCE Then
            /* time out */…
        When ZERO_DIVIDE Then
            /* divide by zero*/…
        When Others Then
           /* others errors */…   
END;
```

Or `PROCEDURE/FUNCTION`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc as
BEGIN
   bulk_cmd;
EXCEPTION
        When NO_DATA_FOUND Then
            /* no value found*/…
        When TIMEOUT_ON_RESOURCE Then
            /* time out */…
        When ZERO_DIVIDE Then
            /* divide by zero*/…
        When Others Then
END;
```

Note that if you rise exception from handling block, it will "eat" your backtrace (backtrace will start not from place where exception occured but from rise function). So it is a good practice don't catch exception that you don't need, and log exception that you catch with backtrace.

Comment: Thank's. so i've just this solution. But just a last question, in t-sql, i've just to compare if the error return '0', so what i've to test ?  Others ? `WHEN ??? then goto lbl_end` What i put in place of ???. Thank's for your answer? Just an add, a create a global temporary table before that : #temp_tb, what i've to put after begin and before EXCEPTION ? like the bulk_cmd

Comment: I write this code, just say me if it's good or not, and what's it's my faults ? I'm french sorry for my approximative english... `DECLARE bulk_cmd varchar2(1000);
        erreur exception
set bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT #temp_tb FROM ''c:\Documents\Communication\MSG_IN\'+'$(nomfic)'+''' WITH 
( 
CODEPAGE = ''RAW'',
ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''',
DATAFILETYPE = ''WIDECHAR'' 
)';

erreur = exec (bulk_cmd);                                                
BEGIN
  bulk_cmd;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN erreur <> 0 THEN GOTO lbl_end
END;` Thank's for your answer you help me a lot. I'm waiting your feedback

Comment: What language did you use when wrote this code?
What did you want to achieve? I may help you to write correct one

Comment: I write in PL/SQL, it's wrong ? yes i see it, just delete the set, in front of bulk_cmd and put : before the = symbol

Comment: Sorry, this is not a PL/SQL... (and seems that PL/SQL is not needed for your task)
If you want to load file into table, there are several ways in Oracle:
SQL Loader: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm
(it is external tool that is used to load file from your local machine)
External table: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm
(it is Oracle mechanism which use same engine as SQL*Loader, but create metadata to query file from server by standard SQL)

Comment: I have to convert this `select '$(nomfic)'

CREATE TABLE #temp_tb ( temp_row nvarchar(max)) 
if @@error <> 0 goto lbl_end

DECLARE @bulk_cmd varchar(1000)
set @bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT #temp_tb FROM ''c:\Documents\Communication\MSG_IN\''+'$(nomfic)'+''' WITH 
( 
CODEPAGE = ''RAW'',
ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''',
DATAFILETYPE = ''WIDECHAR'' 
)'

exec (@bulk_cmd)
if @@error <> 0 goto lbl_end` into pl/sql.

Comment: And i write this : `select '$(nomfic)' CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE #temp_tb ( temp_row NCHAR(max)) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS; 
--i don't know how to convert this
if error <> 0 goto lbl_end;       
DECLARE bulk_cmd varchar2(1000);
        erreur exception;
bulk_cmd := 'BULK INSERT #temp_tb FROM ''c:\Hardis\reflex\Communication\HM\MSG_IN\'+'$(nomfic)'+''' WITH 
( 
CODEPAGE = ''RAW'',
ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''',
DATAFILETYPE = ''WIDECHAR'' 
)';

erreur = exec (bulk_cmd);                                                  
BEGIN
  bulk_cmd;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN erreur <> 0 THEN GOTO lbl_end
END;`

Answer (score 0):

```
set serveroutput on;
declare 
 v number;
begin 

  begin 
    v := 1/0;
  exception when others then 
    dbms_output.put_line('I catch exception;');
    goto my_label;
  end;
  dbms_output.put_line('Something here');
  <<my_label>>
  dbms_output.put_line('After label');
end;
```

Comment: Thank's for your feedback. it's the only method ? Because my script in t-sql is like that : 

`select '$(nomfic)'
CREATE TABLE #temp_tb ( temp_row nvarchar(max)) 
if @@error <> 0 goto lbl_end

DECLARE @bulk_cmd varchar(1000)
set @bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT #temp_tb FROM ''c:\Communication\TEST\MSG_IN\'+'$(nomfic)'+''' WITH 
( 
CODEPAGE = ''RAW'',
ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''',
DATAFILETYPE = ''WIDECHAR'' 
)'

exec (@bulk_cmd)
if @@error <> 0 goto lbl_end`

So adapt just one line with your answer it's really complicated in fact. Because after that i treat a lot of information...